# Путь к файлу не видит JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, path

Пытаюсь css к кнопке прикрутить, но вылазит *ошибка*

> мая 10, 2017 1:37:53 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager 
>   loadStylesheetUnPrivileged    WARNING: Resource
>   "src/May/FX/cssbutton.css" not found.

Почему не найден, если он в папке лежит у меня?

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;


public class HelloJavaFX extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("App");
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("src/May/FX/cssbutton.css");

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setLayoutX(100);
        btn.setLayoutY(80);
        btn.setText("Hello World");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        });
        btn.getStyleClass().add("cssbutton");
        group.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Точно не уверен насчёт JavaFX, но в swing путь начинается с /src/... Так же полностью проверь имя, и регистр букв

Comment: папка src существует только на уровне исходников в проекте. Ее не будет в Jar

Answer (score 0):

При условии что стили лежат в `/src/main/resources`:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add( HelloJavaFX.class.getClassLoader().getResource("cssbutton.css" ).toExternalForm() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от нескольких факторов, система сборки(путь можно коре писать), также у вас путь изначально не правильный обычно он начинается с ./ `./$SRC/*.css`